# Accessing Aurora Postgres Materialized Views from Glue data catalog for Glue Jobs

Tags: amazon-redshift, aws-glue, amazon-aurora, aws-glue-data-catalog

I have an Aurora Serverless instance which has data loaded across 3 tables (mixture of standard and jsonb data types). We currently use traditional views where some of the deeply nested elements are surfaced along with other columns for aggregations and such.

We have two materialized views that we'd like to send to Redshift. Both the Aurora Postgres and Redshift are in Glue Catalog and while I can see Postgres views as a selectable table, the crawler does not pick up the materialized views.

Currently exploring two options to get the data to redshift.

1. Output to parquet and use copy to load
2. Point the Materialized view to jdbc sink specifying redshift.

Wanted recommendations on what might be most efficient approach if anyone has done a similar use case.

Questions:

1. In option 1, would I be able to handle incremental loads?
2. Is bookmarking supported for JDBC (Aurora Postgres) to JDBC (Redshift) transactions even if through Glue?
3. Is there a better way (other than the options I am considering) to move the data from Aurora Postgres Serverless (10.14) to Redshift.

Thanks in advance for any guidance provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Went with option 2. The Redshift Copy/Load process writes csv with manifest to S3 in any case so duplicating that is pointless.

Regarding the Questions:

1. N/A
2. Job Bookmarking does work. There is some gotchas though - ensure Connections both to RDS and Redshift are present in Glue Pyspark job, IAM self ref rules are in place and to identify a row that is unique [I chose the primary key of underlying table as an additional column in my materialized view] to use as the bookmark.
3. Using the primary key of core table may buy efficiencies in pruning materialized views during maintenance cycles. Just retrieve latest bookmark from cli using `aws glue get-job-bookmark --job-name yourjobname` and then just that in the where clause of the mv as `where id >= idinbookmark`

   `conn = glueContext.extract_jdbc_conf("yourGlueCatalogdBConnection")`
   `connection_options_source = { "url": conn['url'] + "/yourdB", "dbtable": "table in dB", "user": conn['user'], "password": conn['password'], "jobBookmarkKeys":["unique identifier from source table"], "jobBookmarkKeysSortOrder":"asc"}`

`datasource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(connection_type="postgresql", connection_options=connection_options_source, transformation_ctx="datasource0")`

That's all, folks